# Swift 3 - inout String is not convertible to String

Tags: ios, swift

Why it doesn't works in Swift 3? How to convert it?

```
var valorTemp: String = "44,52"
valorTemp = valorTemp.substring(with: Range<String.Index>(valorTemp.startIndex...valorTemp.characters.index(valorTemp.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)))
```

When I change ... to ..< it works fine, but I don't think that the result could be the same

```
var valorTemp: String = "44,52"
valorTemp = valorTemp.substring(with: Range<String.Index>(valorTemp.startIndex..<valorTemp.characters.index(valorTemp.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)))
```

Thank you!

Comment: PS: The first code shows me the error "inout String is not convertible to String" in Xcode 8

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, two range operators `...` and `..<` returns two different types. When Applied to `String.Index`, `ClosedRange<String.Index>` and `Range<String.Index>`.

And `substring(with:)` is only defined for `Range<String.Index>` and you cannot convert `ClosedRange<String.Index>` to `Range<String.Index>` with an initializer syntax.

You can try with explicitly using `..<` (just need to modify the lower bound):

```
valorTemp = valorTemp.substring(with: valorTemp.startIndex..<valorTemp.characters.index(valorTemp.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
```

Or else, subscript for `String` has some overloads including both for `Range<String.Index>` and `ClosedRange<String.Index>`:

```
valorTemp = valorTemp[valorTemp.startIndex...valorTemp.characters.index(valorTemp.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)]
```

In your case using `substring(to:)` would be a good alternative (need to use the "modified" index):

```
valorTemp = valorTemp.substring(to: valorTemp.characters.index(valorTemp.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
```